# Does “Lock shat hoo-la ma sho gong um hom tak ti-wak yet gee sam see baa gow!!” mean anything?

Tags: meaning

The book *The Chinese Typewriter* by Thomas Mullaney has the following Cartoon from the San Francisco Examiner (1900)

[image: 8888]

and explanation:

> The first mass-produced Chinese typewriter was a figment of popular imagination. It was first sighted in January 1900, when the San Francisco Examiner spread word of a strange new contraption housed in the city’s Chinatown neighborhood, in the back room of a newspaper office on Dupont Street. The machine boasted a twelve-foot keyboard complete with 5,000 keys. “Two rooms knocked into one apartment afford shelter for this remarkable contrivance,” the author explained, describing a machine so large that the “typist” was something akin to a general commanding forces over a vast terrain (figure 1.1). The piece was accompanied by a cartoon in which the caricatured inventor sat atop a stool and shouted Cantonese-esque gibberish at “four muscular key-thumpers through a large tin megaphone.” Lock shat hoo-la ma sho gong um hom tak ti-wak yet gee sam see baa gow!!

I realize he calls it gibberish but does Lock shat hoo-la ma sho gong um hom tak ti-wak yet gee sam see baa gow!! Actually mean anything?

Comment: It's meaningless from the Chinese perspective.

Comment: pronunications are prosibly changed since that age, and pronuncications given a non-Chinese speakers (he haven't studied Chinese)  are possibly inexact, it is hard to guess what he said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mother-tongue is Cantonese. As far as I understand, this is not anything in Cantonese (at least modern Cantonese). Although some of the words sound like Cantonese, for example “Lock shat” sounds like 落實 (lok6 sat9), I can’t think of any meaningful content when they are put together with the words after that.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely Cantonese since 'yet gee sam see baa gow' sounds exactly like 'one two three four eight nine' in Cantonese, and 'tak ti-wak' sounds like 'make a phone call'.

I don't speak Cantonese, so I cannot give more information on this.

Comment: Not sure about phones in China in 1900.